# Clisp on Windows 10, trying to open a file in a folder with a non-ASCII name

Tags: windows, unicode, filesystems, lisp, common-lisp

I'm working with Clisp 2.49 on Windows 10. I want to open a file (to read or to write) in a folder with a name which contains non-ASCII characters, for example: `foo-dir-᾿Αθηναῖοι`. When I try any file operation, I get an error that the folder does not exist.

Here is a console (`cmd.exe`) session. The operations shown in this session are calls to `TRUENAME`, which seems a suitable test, and calls to `OPEN` trigger the same error.

```
C:\Users\dodier\Temp\foo-dir-᾿Αθηναῖοι>C:\maxima-5.45.1\clisp-2.49\clisp.exe -E UTF-8

[1]> (setq ext:*pathname-encoding* 'charset:utf-8)
#<ENCODING CHARSET:UTF-8 :UNIX>
[2]> (truename #p".")

*** - TRUENAME: Directory #P"C:\\Users\\dodier\\Temp\\foo-dir-?????a???\\" does not exist

[4]> (setq ext:*pathname-encoding* 'charset:cp1251)
#<ENCODING CHARSET:CP1251 :UNIX>
[5]> (truename #p".")

*** - TRUENAME: Directory #P"C:\\Users\\dodier\\Temp\\foo-dir-?????a???\\" does not exist
```

Note that the current working directory is the folder which has non-ASCII characters in its name.

Note that I have launched Clisp with the option `-E UTF-8`. I tried setting `EXT:*PATHNAME-ENCODING*` to plausible values (UTF-8 and CP1251) but neither one works.

Is there a setting or option I can try to help Clisp along here?

Is anyone familiar enough with Clisp internals to say what low level operation is failing when Clisp says the folder does not exist? I am thinking that if I knew, I could try to steer around it.

Comment: There are rumours that the native encoding for filenames in NTFS is UTF-16: have you tried that?

Comment: Hmm, after `(setq ext:*pathname-encoding* 'charset:utf-16)` I get `PARSE-NAMESTRING: syntax error in filename "." at position 0`, so I guess that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error on macOS, and I found that building a current version from Git (https://gitlab.com/gnu-clisp/clisp) fixed the problem. I tried to do the same on Windows, but I'm running into compiler errors; apparently some code which is accepted by gcc on other platforms is rejected by gcc on windows. For the record I'm working with gcc 11 installed via Cygwin.

So in summary my guess is that the observed behavior is a bug in Clisp which has been fixed in recent versions, although I'm unable to verify that directly.